# Will the class method call be optimized out in the for loop?

Tags: c++, optimization

code

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < myClassObject.Method(); ++i)
  some work;
```

I am wondering if the compiler will optimize out the method call and turn it into this?

```
size_t result = myClassObject.Method();
for (size_t i = 0; i < result; ++i
  some work;
```

Would it matter if it was a function call instead?  My worry is that I could be doing 1000's of unneeded calls to the method, but I prefer to write it with the method call in the condition.

Comment: Similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607762/what-does-code-motion-mean-for-loop-invariant-code-motion

Comment: Doesn't matter if it's a method call or a plain C-style function call, the requirements for the compiler to be allowed to optimize it out are the same.

Comment: This is subject to the widely implemented loop hoisting optimization, aka "loop-invariant code motion".  So, yes.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should state in code what you want to do. If you need a sum, you wouldn't write code that multiplies instead of adding just because you prefer to do so. It needs a smart compiler to realize that the call to `Method()` has no side effects, and that the loop of the body does not modify the parameters used within `Method()` directly or indirectly in any way.

My personal preference, in order to do what I want and write it as I like it, is:

```
for (size_t i = 0, result = myClassObject.Method(); i < result; ++i )
   some work;
```

Comment: I checked your answer so you can have your whiskey evening.  Thanks @Kerrek also

Answer (score 4):

It depends on whether the compiler can prove that the result of the call cannot possibly change in the loop body, so don't rely on it. If you want to do the hoisting explicitly, the standard way to write it is like this:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0, end = myClassObject.Method(); i != end; ++i)
{
  // ...
}
```

The same applies to iterator-based loops.

Comment: We are usually on the same line with our answers, we should start a club! :P

Comment: @K-ballo: I suggest shifts, so I can have SO-free whisky evenings :-)

Answer (score 1):

As a rule this would be an incorrect optimization, as the method may not return the same result on every call. Consider if it returned the current time.

**If** the method definition is available in the same compilation unit (in an included header file or the same source file) **and** it's simple enough for the compiler to tell it always returns the same result, then you **may** get this optimization. I think this is especially likely if the method is declared `inline`.

I believe gcc at least now has inter-module optimization with some compile flags, that may also do it across source file boundaries. No idea about other compilers.